# Creating slightly different sites using same code base

Tags: multi-sites

We are looking to create templated sites that have the same basic structure with the following differences. We would want to look up which site is being created based on domain/subdomain.

- Same navigation, but links to different node. ex: About Page has different content
- Different logo/header throughout the site.

Is there a module or suggested approach to do this?

NOTE: We want to use the same codebase and database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is called a "multi-site".  It allows you to use the same codebase for multiple sites.  Each site in a multi-site has its own `settings.php`, so you may use different databases or the same database (this is controlled by the database settings in `settings.php`.

To use a different logo, just  go to `appearance > settings` and upload a different image for the logo.

Here is a link to my tutorial about setting up a multi-site:
http://wikihandbooks.com/drupal7/intro_multisite.html

There is also instructions at Drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite/multi-site-sharing-the-same-code-base

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to use the same drupal instance to make another site.

Yes you can do all these which you have asked. You will have to copy the instance & set at different location(where ever you want, either at your local or sub-domain).

To change the logo, you will have to go to appearance->theme->setting & upload new image for logo.

You can go to your content list & edit the content of ABOUT US to change the page content of your about us link.

Other things like site name can be changed from site setting in configuration area of the site.

Comment: I forgot one key point. We want to use the same codebase and database

Comment: @ChrisMuench - Thats multisite then, Gisle has answered you for that... Good Luck :)